# How to start building DApps

Tags: solidity, react, django

Hello guys I am a beginner trying to learn how to build DApps and i have knowledge about ethereum and bitcoin i know how both of these work i wanted to get my hands dirty with how to start building DApps i have experience with Django(python framework to build full stack websites) and have a basic knowledge about React can someone please tell me what is the tech stack required for building DApps and if i need to learn other technologies like expressjs and nodejs or i can just use react and solidity to build fully functional DApps
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To start building DApps, first, choose a blockchain like Ethereum or Polygon. Then, learn Solidity, the language for smart contracts. Next, pick a front-end framework such as React, Vue, or Angular to create your user interface. Use Web3.js or Ethers.js to connect your app to the blockchain. Explore options for oracles, storage, and authentication to add more features. Check out these resources to get started:

**Blockchain Selection:**

- Ethereum - https://ethereum.org/
- Polygon - https://polygon.technology/developers

**Solidity Mastery:**

- Solidity docs - https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/

**Front-end Frameworks:**

- React: https://reactjs.org/
- Vue: https://vuejs.org/
- Angular: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

**Blockchain Interaction:**

- Web3.js: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/
- Ethers.js: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/

**Platforms:**

- [OpenZeppelin: A widely-used library for secure smart contract development and deployment.](https://www.openzeppelin.com/)
- [CryptoZombies: An interactive platform for learning blockchain development through building simple games.](https://cryptozombies.io/)
- [Learn Blockchain, Solidity, and Full Stack Web3 Development with JavaScript – 32-Hour Course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyMwXuJrbJQ)

Commence with small projects, experiment, and continue learning!